# Return value from recursive method (java)

Tags: java, recursion

I have to write a recursive method to sum the figures of an integer.

The method works fine, but I don't understand why it returns the last integer instead of the total.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class SommaCifreRicorsivo{
    public static void main (String[] args){
        System.out.printf("Inserire un numero: ");
        Scanner tastiera = new Scanner(System.in);
        int numero = tastiera.nextInt();
        int somma = 0;

        int risultato = eseguiSomma(numero,somma);
        System.out.println("La somma delle sue cifre è " + risultato);
    }

    public static int eseguiSomma(int numero, int somma){
        //Caso base
        if (numero < 10) {
            somma = somma + numero;
            System.out.println("Aggiungo la cifra " + numero + " alla somma, ottenendo " + somma);
            return (somma += numero);
        }

        //Chiamate ricorsive
        somma = somma + numero%10;
        System.out.println("Aggiungo la cifra " + (numero%10) + " alla somma, ottenendo " + somma);
        eseguiSomma((numero/10), somma);

        return somma;

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`somma` is a fundamental type (`int`), so Java passes it by value. This means the value you are modifying is just a *copy* of `somma` stored on the stack frame of each recursive call, not the final return value.

Because of this, the argument `somma` is entirely unnecessary. You should instead return the return value of the recursive call plus the new digit. This gives a much simpler solution.

```
public static int eseguiSomma(int numero){
    //Caso base
    if (numero < 10) {
        return numero;
    }

    //Chiamate ricorsive
    return numero % 10 + eseguiSomma(numero / 10);
}

// now simply call without somma
int risultato = eseguiSomma(numero);
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply correct it to :

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class SommaCifreRicorsivo{
    public static void main (String[] args){
        System.out.printf("Inserire un numero: ");
        Scanner tastiera = new Scanner(System.in);
        int numero = tastiera.nextInt();
        int somma = 0;

        int risultato = eseguiSomma(numero,somma);
        System.out.println("La somma delle sue cifre è " + risultato);
    }

    public static int eseguiSomma(int numero, int somma){
        //Caso base
        if (numero < 10) {
            somma = somma + numero;
            System.out.println("Aggiungo la cifra " + numero + " alla somma, ottenendo " + somma);
            return (somma += numero);
        }

        //Chiamate ricorsive
        somma = somma + numero%10;
        System.out.println("Aggiungo la cifra " + (numero%10) + " alla somma, ottenendo " + somma);

        // the error was on this line!
        somma += eseguiSomma((numero/10), somma);

        return somma;

    }
}
```

You are trying to modify somma, but somma is a raw type so you only modify its local copy and somma remains unchanged.

Comment: Yes sorry, I did write = instead of +=, correcting my answer right away, thanks!